# 'is been created' vs 'have been created'

Tags: sentence-meaning, difference, tense, verbs

In answering a question from right from of verb, I filled the gap with the phrase 'was created', but in the answer sheet the correct answer was 'is been created / has been created'.

Now I am confused, what is the difference between 'is been created' and 'has been created' and what is the similarity between these two phrases?

Answer (score 6):

"is been created" is grammatically wrong and **cannot** be used, check [this out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87608/is-is-been-a-valid-construction) when trying to use "is been".

"has been created" implies the event occurred very recently/in progress. Since "has been" is present perfect tense, it refers to an action that began at some time in the past and is still in progress.

E.g.

> The party **has been** great so far!

The above sentence shows how the person is enjoying the part that is *currently* still going on.

Comment: "try to avoid using it" is weak, and possibly misleading. Better would be 'this is wrong, don't ever use it'. Also we can say 'the house has been unbearably lonely without you' even if someone left a long time ago.

Comment: To address the question in the title (which doesn't quite match the text), the difference between "*has* been created" and "*have* been created" is that the first has a singular subject and the second is plural.

Answer (score 1):

Contrasting "is' to "have" is confusing as the first is singular and the second is plural, so let me start by making a slight change to your question:

> What is the differences between '<strike>is been created</strike>' vs 'has been created'

As you can guess by the strikethrough, the first form is wrong. I think you probably meant "is being created".

So here is the difference:

"Is being created" means it is in the process of creation. This process is underway, started but not finished yet:

*Something special is being created in our town. Hopefully we'll get a chance to see it from close quarters when it is completed.*

"Has been created" means that the creation process is complete and we can see the result:

*Something special has been created in our town. You may not have heard about it but you can discover it by simply taking a stroll in the central park.*